# Resorting array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

At first I want to metion that **I know how to solve this task with array.sort** and it is most acceptable way. 
But I want to understand why my actions failed. So I have 2 arrays - v_a, whuch consists from 3 values - '1','2','3' and empty array v_a_resorted, where I want to store v_a values arranged in random order. 
So, logicaly, I get random value in v_a, splice it in v_a, and push it to v_a_resoreted. Without For it looks for me in this way:

```js
 var v_a = new Array ('1','2','3');
 var v_a_resorted = [];
 var v_a_l = v_a.length;
 var r_v_a_n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (v_a_l - 0+0)) + 0;
 v_a.splice(r_v_a_n, 1);
 v_a_resorted.push(v_a[r_v_a_n]);
 document.write("<b>Random number</b> -" + r_v_a_n + "<br>"); 
 document.write("<b>Transportation unit</b> -" + v_a[r_v_a_n] + "<br>");
 document.write("<b>Old Array</b> -" + v_a + "<br>"); 
 document.write("<b>New Array</b> -" + v_a_resorted + "<br>");
```

But it doesn't work. E.g. if Random number = 1, than Transportation unit = 2 and old array = 1,3 and new array = 2.
But in my case it's: Random number = 1, Transportation unit=3, Old array = 1,3 and New Array = 3.

But why?

Comment: It might make it easier for people to read if you rename your variables. Instead of letters, use words. `arrayLength`, `sortedArray` etc.

Comment: ^agreed. They're actually quite distracting in a weird way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you remove an element from the first array and try to push it (being already removed with `splice`) to the second one
Changing `splice` and `push` calls does what you are trying to achieve

```js
 var v_a = new Array ('1','2','3');
 var v_a_resorted = [];
 var v_a_l = v_a.length;
 var r_v_a_n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (v_a_l - 0+0)) + 0;
    document.write("<b>Random number</b> -" + r_v_a_n + "<br>"); 
 document.write("<b>Transportation unit</b> -" + v_a[r_v_a_n] + "<br>");
 v_a_resorted.push(v_a[r_v_a_n]);//this line
    v_a.splice(r_v_a_n, 1);//and this one     
 
 document.write("<b>Old Array</b> -" + v_a + "<br>"); 
 document.write("<b>New Array</b> -" + v_a_resorted + "<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question was answered in another post.

[How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Comment: If you believe it's been answered before, you should flag it as a duplicate, not an answer.

Comment: Answered, yes, and I solved it by myself already. But the question is why and not how.